# What is the correct syntax for search & replace within an Ansible playbook?

Tags: regex, ansible

I'm writing an Ansible playbook which will install and configure an agent of some monitoring system my company uses.
One of the steps required for the successful configuration of the agent is to configure Nagios "log_rotation_method" to daily.
The relevant line in `nagios.cfg` file is:
`log_rotation_method=h` which I'd like Ansible to change to `log_rotation_method=d`.

The relevant portion of the playbook looks like so:

```
- name: Set Nagios rotation method to daily
  replace: dest=/etc/nagios3/nagios.cfg regexp='log_rotation_method=h' replace='log_rotation_method=d'
```

In bash I would write something like this:

```
sed -i 's/^log_rotation_method.*/log_rotation_method=d/g' nagios.cfg
```

But I'm having a hard time understanding how it should be written in Ansible which is Python based.

Any idea how it should be written? 
An explanation would be more than welcomed.

Comment: Try `replace: dest=/etc/nagios3/nagios.cfg regexp='(?m)^log_rotation_method.*' replace='log_rotation_method=d'` (or with `(?m)` removed)

Comment: note that how it **should** be written is in a `template`. The `lineinfile` module means you aren't ensuring the rest of your nagios configuration is managed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a very similar thing to what you would write in bash ( they're both regexps in the end ):

```
   replace: dest=/etc/nagios3/nagios.cfg regexp='^log_rotation_method.*' replace='log_rotation_method=d'
```

It should actually work even the same way you have written. It will just match that exact string instead of multiple in case of a regex.

Answer (score 1):

I would do that with lineinfile:

```
- lineinfile: dest=/etc/nagios3/nagios.cfg regexp='^log_rotation_method.*' line='log_rotation_method=d'
```